# Sum Values from Dataset based on condition: Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report where users can select items from various location. And I have 3 datasets performing calculations where the third dataset takes the sum where item number is 4942200 and then calculates the values (as shown below):

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!masterno.Value= "4942200",Fields!Owned.Value,0))+SUM(IIf(Fields!masterno.Value= "4942200",Fields!Subbed.Value,0))
```

This is returning error for some reason. The subbed column is toggled based on parameter (visibility). But before I add the toggle functionality, I want to make sure this is working. Can anyone help. I have also tried:

```
 =SUM(IIf(Fields!masterno.Value= "4942200",Fields!Owned.Value+Fields!Subbed.Value,0))
```

This seems to fail as well. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: error messages or the like would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: It just says #Error...

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap a CDec around Owned, 0 and Subbed, e.g.

`=SUM(IIf(Fields!masterno.Value= "4942200",CDec ( Fields!Owned.Value) ,CDec (0 ) ))+SUM(IIf(Fields!masterno.Value= "4942200",CDec (Fields!Subbed.Value ) ,CDec ( 0 )))`

If Owned and Subbed are already Decimals, those CDec's may be redundant.  On the other hand SSRS doesnt expose this info and they can change at the whim of the data source.